# Defined matrix in Catmull Spline Curve

Tags: geometry, algebraic-curves, interpolation, spline

I am trying to use Catmull spline curve in my program , I am trying to understand it but why we only use below given Matrix , because the examples I saw I only found the below one

[image]

In Catmull spline curve , why its speciality ? and if we can use other matrix then how and what change it effects ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Catmull-Rom spline is just a sequence of cubic segments, strung together so that their tangents match at the junctions.

You can think of each cubic segment in ["Hermite" form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline). This means the segment is defined in terms of its end-points $\mathbf{p}_0$ and $\mathbf{p}_1$ and its end tangents $\mathbf{m}_0$ and $\mathbf{m}_1$. Because two adjacent cubic segments share the same point and tangent, they join smoothly.

Of course, you do this same construction with **any** set of points $\mathbf{p}_i$ and tangent vectors $\mathbf{m}_i$. Usually the points $\mathbf{p}_i$ are given, and the splining function somehow makes up a set of tangent vectors $\mathbf{m}_i$. Different splining techniques make up the tangent vectors in different ways. The Catmull-Rom spline calculates the tangent vector $\mathbf{m}_i$ just by scaling the vector $\mathbf{p}_{i+1} - \mathbf{p}_{i-1}$. That's where the matrix comes from. [This page](https://cse.taylor.edu/~btoll/s99/424/res/ucdavis/CAGDNotes/Catmull-Rom-Spline/Catmull-Rom-Spline.html) shows the derivation.

You can invent some other way to fabricate the tangents $\mathbf{m}_i$, and this would give rise to a different matrix. There is nothing really special about the Catmull-Rom approach or its associated matrix.